# Paypal preapproval payment through simple html form

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I saw a simple HTML form for simple PayPal payment(for test's purposes, with test data and stuff, according to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/).

My question: is there a simple way to make a request for Paypal preapproval payment through the HTML form?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Yes you can.but it wont be safe and controlable.you want simple code or suggestion ?

Comment: I've used suggestion in curl that are on paypal page, but I failed. Simple code would be nice :)